# Passing List<T> Model to a Controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a form in my web application for evaluation and it has several questions and each question, several answers which should be chosen by user (radio buttons).

My model looks like:

```
public class EvaluationQuestionModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  
  public string Title { get; set; }

  public List<EvaluationAnswerModel> Answers { get; set; }

  public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }

}
```

(and my Answers model:

```
public class EvaluationAnswerModel
{
   public string Title { get; set; }

   public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

)

And my view looks like:

```
@model List<EvaluationQuestionModel>

<form asp-controller="EvaluationQuestions" asp-action="SubmitSurvey">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                <label>@Model[i].Title</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Answers.Count; j++)
                {
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="@Model[i].SelectedAnswer" name="@Model[i].Id" type="radio" value="@Model[i].Answers[j].Grade">
                        <label asp-for="@Model[i].Answers[j].Title" class="form-check-label">@Model[i].Answers[j].Title</label>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    }
    <div class="row no-block d-flex justify-content-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

I can't seem to find a way to pass the model to my controller. I want to have the answer for each question, I wonder if anyone can help me out.

//UPDATE

I actually solved it with two modifications:

1. binding the input like this: `[@i].SelectedAnswer` instead of `@Model[i].SelectedAnswer`
2. using the 'name' property instead of 'asp-for'

Comment: IEnumerable<EvaluationQuestionModel> ?

Comment: no, it wouldn't help. Actually I first did it with IEnumerable and then used List<T>.

Comment: how about keeping `object` and then checking what kind of object its receiving

Comment: I didn't get what you meant. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: Object is supermost class can receive any type of subtype including IEnumerable<T> or List<T> so if you can keep object type to receive data in controller from cshtml ? then you can verify what type of object you are receiving to make further changes ?

Comment: I did that and still no data is passed. Perhaps there's sth wrong with the way I bound the data in view?

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass your formdata to backend, your data format in your request should be like below:

```
[{Id:1,SelectedAnswer:1},{Id:2,SelectedAnswer:2},{Id:3,SelectedAnswer:3}]
```

Then you can get list model by `FromForm`, like

`public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitSurvey([FromForm] List<EvaluationQuestionModel> data){}`

#### Tips

You need make sure your properties in http request as same as model in backend, it will works fine.

I create a sample code you provided and test it, I saw the data.

[image]

## My Solution

I can foreach `IFormCollection`, then convert them to list.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitSurvey(IFormCollection formCollection)
{
    List<EvaluationQuestionModel> data = new List<EvaluationQuestionModel>();

    foreach (var item in formCollection)
    {
        if (item.Key != "__RequestVerificationToken")
        {
            EvaluationQuestionModel e = new EvaluationQuestionModel();
            e.Id = int.Parse(item.Key);
            e.SelectedAnswer = int.Parse(item.Value);
            data.Add(e);
        }
    }
    return Ok(data);
}
```

Then you can get the data in backend.

[image]